# Is it possible to get the item count of a List<T> when T is different?

Tags: c#, generics, list

I have a subroutine that changes its operation slightly to include either one list or the other then perform the same operation. Since it is just counting the number of items in the list, I figure there is probably an easy way to get the item count regardless of the list type.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
private List<Message> currentMessages;
private List<Lead> currentLeads; 
...
private void nextLeadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object temp;
        if (includeAllCheck.Checked)
        {

            temp = currentMessages;
            if (SelectedLead == (currentMessages.Count - 1))
                SelectedLead = 0;
            else
                SelectedLead += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = currentLeads;
            if (SelectedLead == (currentLeads.Count - 1))
                SelectedLead = 0;
            else
                SelectedLead += 1;  
        }
        // This is what I want to replace the above with
        //if (SelectedLead == ((List)temp).Count - 1) //obviously this does not work
        //    SelectedLead = 0;
        //else
        //    SelectedLead += 1;




        LoadPreviews(includeAllCheck.Checked);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you "count" the number of items in a list rather than acessing the Count property?

Comment: I believe it is the ambiguousness of the List<T>, I'll add some code to show better what I am doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use `ICollection.Count`, if you don't want to deal with generics. `List<T>` implements `ICollection`, so you can always access that.

EDIT: So now that you've posted your code, you can just change the line:

```
if (SelectedLead == ((List)temp).Count - 1)  // won't compile, of course
```

to

```
if (SelectedLead == ((ICollection)temp).Count - 1)  // happy as a clam
```

In fact, **an even better option** would be to change the declaration of `object temp` to `ICollection temp` to better convey the type information, and avoid all of this casting nonsense altogether.

Comment: Perfect, this did exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Also took your better option. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
ICollection temp;
        if (includeAllCheck.Checked)
        {

            temp = currentMessages;            
        }
        else
        {
            temp = currentLeads;

        }
if (SelectedLead == (temp.Count - 1))
                SelectedLead = 0;
            else
                SelectedLead += 1;
```

Comment: This was the proper solution to my inquiry. LBushkin gave it away just before you did. Thanks for your input, however!